# Writing a Select Where statement in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

Would someone please me with the code below, I am inexperienced in this area and my class in SQL was "A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away..."  I know the connection string works because I have used it in other functions with this app.  I have even used the code below for retrieving *rows from another table in another function, for the most part, except that I didn't use the WHERE clause.

First, I am able to store IP addresses in the table using a function and it is working well. Now I want to check to see if a given one exist in this table. Partial code is given below.

What seems to always return is 0 rows.  I have put in test data into the table and hard-coded the $ipA, but I still get 0 rows return.  Please help if possible and thanks for the effort spent.

```
function checkDB($ipA) {    

    require_once('connection.inc.php');

    $resultAns = "";    

    //create db connection
    $conn = dbConnect();               

    //init prepared stmt
    $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();

    //Set sql query for ipAddress search
    //prepare the SQL query
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ipAddress WHERE ipA = ?'; 

    //submit the query and capture the result   
    if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {                 
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $ipA);
        $stmt = $stmt->execute();

        //if qry triggers error affeted_rows value becomes -1  & 
        //php treats -1 as true; so test for greater than 0

        $numRows = $stmt->num_rows;     //not to sure about the syntax here
     } 


    // I want to know if the query brought back something or not, I don't what
    // to know exactly what, only that it found a match or did not find a match.
    // echos are for testing purposes to show me where I am landing.

    if ($numRows == 0) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.alert("numRows = 0")</script>';
        $resultAns = 0;
    } elseif ($numRows == 1) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.alert("numRows = 1")</script>';
        $resultAns = 1;
    }

    return $resultAns;
```

}

Comment: Ok, I added $stmt->store-result();  as suggested below and mentioned in my books, but I receive a "Fatal error: Call to a member function store_result() on a non-object on line 31".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try storing the result after you execute

```
$stmt->store_result();
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming that I needed this line of code.  I was in my book, but I overlooked it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$stmt->store_result();` before you call `num_rows`.

Answer (score 0):

While the others caught one reason that $numRows would never receive a value other than 0, the other piece of code that was flawed and caused problems was...

**$stmt = $stmt->execute()**; which should have been just  **$stmt->execute();**

I must have mixed it up with other code I wrote from somewhere else.

Thanks for the answers, they did help.